# Why do I get an Angular compile error in this simple component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have just "written" (copied structure not content) this little Angular 4 module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpModule } from "@angular/http";

import { FooterComponent } from "./footer.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [FooterComponent]
})
export class FooterModule { }
```

When I try an `angular build`, I get the following error:

> ERROR in C:/Projects/Angular 4/Angular4/src/footer.module.ts (7,1):
>   'from' expected.

To me, line 7, `import { FooterComponent } from "./footer.component";`, looks syntactically correct, and even has a `from`. If the `from` component is bad, I'd rather expect a runtime error.

Comment: Did you try deleting and rewriting (not copy past) this line and the lines before?

Comment: try to clean cache and restart

Comment: @Guy, yes, I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I didn't include a `*.Module.ts` for my Components. That was tripping up the `import's` and all sorts of things. I got a clue with a red line under my component decorators; hovering over the line told me my module could not be used here and there.

Adding Module files solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Type the following:

```
import { } from "./footer.component";
```

Then place the cursor inside the curlies and hit Ctrl-Space in your IDE. See if it suggests FooterComponent. If not, the issue is in the footer.component.ts.